# Поиск картинок font awesome

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, fontawesome

Подскажите, можно ли как то автоматизировать процесс нахождения иконок?
В макете много Font-awesome. И очень долго получается вводить в font-awesome, то на чо похожа картинка и искать нужную. Особенно когда картинки эио не просто домик, птичка и т.д.,а что то где сложее подобать название

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если иконка вставлена в макет как текст:
1) скопировать символ;
2) Зайти на https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/ ;
3) Нажать `Ctrl + F`, затем `Ctrl + V` ; 
4) ??? 
5) Profit!